# How to choose the right Google Maps product?

Tags: google-maps

I'm new to Maps APIs. I have this requirement to display maps with markers in my web Application. We did some research and decided to use Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

But I see there are a lot more products available and I'm just confused. We have:

Google Maps Engine
   Maps JavaScript API v3
   Google My Maps

Where is the big picture on this? Is there a map to map these Maps products (pun intended)? How do I choose? My application is a web application to be supported across all devices.

Comment: You can start here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/ there are a lot of code examples in the documentation

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I'm still confused. How is the JavaScript APIv3 related to My Maps and Maps Engine.. What licenses are we supposed to get?

Comment: You need to use JavaScript API v3. My maps is just for making custom maps. Youuse the javascript api, you need to obtain an API key https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial. Check the usage limits here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage#usage_limits

Answer (score 0):

[Google Maps Engine API](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/) (Deprecated) provides a means to store geographic data and to layer that data on top of the Google base map. The data can consist of vector and/or raster (imagery) files.

The API provides full functionality for uploading the data into Google Maps Engine, for processing and maintaining the data, and for associating the data with the Google Maps Engine components that interact with the Google map.

[My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/): Create custom maps to share and publish online with Google My Maps. You can make maps that show different kinds of information, like dog-friendly hiking spots.

[JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) enable world-class map features in your web site, including styled maps, 3D buildings, indoor floor plans, geocoding, place data, and more. You need to be familiar with JavaScript programming and object-oriented programming concepts.